# Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to include the config file of a subfolder in the published result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio, build

When you right click on an ASP.NET project/Publish in Visual Studio, the release files will be created.

But if a subfolder has a config file, they won't be included in the final release.

e.g.

```
Root/Web.config // this will be included by default
Root/Admin/Web.Config // this won't be included by default
```

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to include the config file of a subfolder in the published result?

Thanks

Comment: Is it included in the project? Is the resource type to Content and copy to output directory to true?

Answer (score 2):

Mark its `CopyToOutputDirectory` property to Always or If newer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a web *application* project (not a web *site*), just click on the file in the solution explorer, and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to show the properties (if they aren't already showing). Make sure "Copy to Output Directory" is something other than "Do not copy" (i.e. "Copy if newer" or "Copy always"), and... that's it.